# How to create an Openlayers Map with Famo.us in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, famo.us, openlayers-3

I want to have an *Openlayers* Map in *Meteor* with *Famo.us*. How would I do that?

So far I have taken a look at *IjzerenHein/famous-map* but it doesn't provide *Openlayers* support which I need because of the rotation functionality.
With *Famo.us*, rotation probably could be programmed, but is a big effort I suppose until you have a smooth two finger zoom-pan-rotate interaction with the map that's already integrated into *Openlayers 3* and *Google Maps* (but only the native *Android/iOS* version, not in *JS*).

I've tried it with *gaddicohen's famous-views* package, but no map is showing up.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Another thing is: What is the problem at all? Why isn't the map showing up, I mean *Openlayers* is a *JS*-library and I thought everything that can be displayed in a div can also be shown in a *Famo.us Surface*?

Unfortunately I am missing some insights about how *Famo.us* etc. are built up.

Regards

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to add OpenLayers 3 support to https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-map. Since it's a rainy day today, I'll see if I can come up with a pull request. Stay tuned.

Comment: Ok, cool, let's see then.

Comment: See https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-map/pull/19.

Comment: Thank you, that was really fast. 
I tried to install famous-maps earlier, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Meteor yet. Seems to be a problem with 
define, requireJS or so, idunno. I will try to come up with a solution, but since I am pretty new to the webworld I don't know how far I will get.
Unfortunately I cannot mark your answer as correct since you only commented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only answer the first part of the question: https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-map/ does not support OpenLayers 3 yet, but I created a pull request that adds OpenLayers 3 support. The pull request also adds support for map rotation: https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-map/pull/19.

Comment: Thank you again, @ahocevar, together with fview-map this should go.